# Desktop application + SQLite - Version=1.0.65.0 vs. Version 1.0.104.0

Tags: c#, .net, sqlite, visual-studio-2015

I am currently writing a desktop application (nothing hosted in `IIS` or similar, .NET 4.5.2) which makes use of `SQLite` and the Entity Provider for `SQLite`. For this to get it to work in Visual Studio, I had to install the 1.0.65.0 version package from the `SQLite` site to get the `EF6` provider for `SQLite` inside Visual Studio. This worked as expected ad as far as I understood, this is also the only way this can be done.

For my application, I would like to use the current version which is 1.0.104.0 (again, info from the sqlite page). I have successfully added the `Nuget` package for this version to my application and when I look into the references tab, I can see `System.Data.SQLite`, `System.Data.SQLite.EF6` and `System.Data.SQLite.Linq`, all with the version 1.0.104.0 and Specific Version set to True. Copy Local is set to true for all three of them.

So now when I run my application and get to the line:

```
using (var ctx = new SmtAoiLookupEntities())
{
  foreach (var lu in ctx.Lookups.Where(d=>!string.IsNullOrEmpty(d.Aoi)))
  {
      ...
  }
}
```

I get the following error message:

> An exception of type 'System.IO.FileLoadException' occurred in mscorlib.dll and wasn't handled before a managed/native boundary
>
> Additional information: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Data.SQLite, Version=1.0.65.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=db937bc2d44ff139' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

From this, I understand that my application tries to load version 1.0.65.0, although all my references point to 1.0.104.0. I have absolutely no idea where my application gets the idea that I want to load 1.0.65.0. I even did a find in files to catch any reference to "1.0.65" with absolutely no results.

I used

```
gacutil -l System.Data.SQLite
```

to see which Assemblies are stored in the GAC -> Version 1.0.104.0

Now, this appears only to happen when I run the application from within Visual Studio; If I run the application outside Visual Studio as an executable I get a different error when saving the context. It appears that this is an application error and not related to the assembly version problem. I have also tried setting the application to a 32bit application, the issue stays the same.

The main issue: I would like to be able to debug the application inside Visual Studio, otherwise this could become quite cumbersome. Any ideas how I tell Visual Studio not to load the 1.0.65.0 libs?

Comment: Try cleaning the solution and manually delete `bin` and `obj` folders.

Comment: I did that multiple times but it didn't change a thing. And as I said, the application appears to work outside Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1):

A project in your solution is still pointing to previous SQLite version. In my case it was the project which file was throwing the error. Making sure every project in the solution has the updated package version solved the problem for me.

Comment: Unfortunately it's a single project inside the solution. No dependencies on other projects whatsoever. For now, I decided to switch to something which is better supported and stay away from SQLite. The requirements changed anyway so this wasn't a hard decision.